# Cant access PFUsers from Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfuser

I am new to parse and ios development. 
I want to use Parse for User management of an IOS app. With the help of documentation (https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-signing-up) I was able to signup some sample users and I have the following in Parse app.

[image]

Then I want to retrieve all users (or query for specific) with following documentation help.

```
var query = PFUser.query()
query.whereKey("gender", equalTo:"female")
var girls = query.findObjects()
```

I was expected to receive an array of size 3 but surprisingly didn't receive any.

Later I figured out I can user API console feature of Parse and tried use it to receive `PFUser` objects. I received zero results.

Later I tried with sample table and I was successfully add, retrieve Objects to the table.

Not sure If I need to anything special for me to use `PFUser`.

Comment: can you share your pfuser table schema so that I can get a clue of gender key in your user table ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested using **API Console** and its working on my side. I have one entry in **User** table having gender = male.

I fired following curl query to retry all the users

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <#your-application-key>" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: <#your-rest-api-key>" \
  -G \
  https://api.parse.com/1/users
```

Result from the above query is:

```
  {"results":[{"gender":"male","createdAt":"2015-12-10T06:00:40.368Z","email":"sam07it22@gmail.com","objectId":"1KbxpYgeUb","updatedAt":"2015-12-10T06:01:32.885Z","username":"sam07it22@gmail.com"}]}
```

Now, I'm going to add Condition in above query to fetch records having gender = female. As per data expected result should have zero records

**For gender = female**

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <#your-application-key>" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: <#your-rest-api-key>" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"gender":"female"}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/users
```

**Output:**

```
{"results":[]}
```

**For gender = male**

```
 curl -X GET \
      -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <#your-application-key>" \
      -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: <#your-rest-api-key>" \
      -G \
      --data-urlencode 'where={"gender":"male"}' \
      https://api.parse.com/1/users
```

**Output:**

```
{"results":[{"gender":"male","createdAt":"2015-12-10T06:00:40.368Z","email":"sam07it22@gmail.com","objectId":"1KbxpYgeUb","updatedAt":"2015-12-10T06:01:32.885Z","username":"sam07it22@gmail.com"}]}
```

**NOTE:**
Don't forget to replace your **API KEY** and **REST API KEY**

Answer (score 0):

ACL permissions has done the trick. ACL permissions has to be "public read" for them to be accessible. Here is more info about ACL in parse https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#security-object-level-access-control